# How can I tell how many devices are in provisioning profile from Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, xcode8, provisioning-profile

This is frustrating me to say the least.  I have a Xamarin.Forms app I'm developing on Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015 with the latest of everything from Xamarin (as of this post).  The Mac agent is running, and is also up to date with the latest as of this post.  Xcode is 8.3.

So, the issue I'm having is when I add a device to the provisioning profile on the apple developer site.  From the site, I generate the profile, and download it, then click on the profile which opens XCode (and assuming installs the profile).  I've also downloaded the profile by using XCode 8.3, logging into my account and clicking download profiles.

The devices NEVER show up when I build the app.  I deploy the app to HockeyApp and it does not show the new devices in the build. If I could see which profile VS2015 would be using and how many devices are in there, I could eliminate a very annoying cycle of build, publish, see the devices aren't there, try again.

I have tried, restarting VS2015.  I have tried rebooting the Mac, rebooting the Windows box, and nothing.  What voodoo do I need to do to get this to consistently recognize when I've added a new device?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this is a permissions thing?  After downloading the profile (through XCode and the dev site) the build from VS2015 STILL does not have the new devices .  So, I opened finder and deleted the profile files from the folder, THEN downloaded, restarted VS2015, build, publish to HockeyApp and now the new devices are there.  So, why doesn't XCode give me some kind of hint as to the status of the profiles?  Frustrating...  Shouldn't have to do this every time I add a device for Beta testing.

Comment: After downloading the latest profile, can you confirm that the installed profile has the device IDs for the devices that you added.  The quit Xcode, and then restart VS / Xamarin Studio? The instructions here (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/#Add_a_Device) seem to indicate that you need to quit Xcode and restart your IDE for it to work.

Comment: @wottle Thank you!  Didn't see that part, at least now it should be consistent.  This should be the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can either find a text editor that supports binary plists and open it with that, the TextEdit application on Mac should be able to or just Xcode.

Or you can check it with this command in a Mac Terminal window:

```
security cms -D -i /path/to/MyProfile.mobileprovision
```

Where the path should point to your file of course.

As to the comment to this answer; go into Xcode, find the Preferences window and then Accounts. Select your 'team' and open it. You should then be able to view the profiles and delete them as well. Try to re-import it then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I guess to be more specific, I know the profile is updated on the mac, but when I build the Xamarin.Forms app on Windows 10 box, it doesn't seem to be using the latest profile, even though there is only one select-able profile in the project properties.  It's almost like it's cached somewhere.

Comment: Added a bit, see if it helps. Else we need to investigate a bit further :)

Comment: When I open XCode 8.3, go to preferences, accounts, select my apple id, and click on my team, it takes me to the certs but I can do nothing with them.  I can highlight my team and I have two buttons, "Download All Profiles" and "Manage Certificates..."  With previous versions of XCode I could see the profiles, now all I can do is download all and assume that worked.